# Installing a gem from a repo I cloned on git hub

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github

Post says it all.

I've cloned a gem (particularly radiant) after clone it from its github source.  Anybody tell me how I can install it as a gem?

Something like "gem install radiant --local"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the dir of your cloned repo and run this:

```
$ rake build
```

This will create gem file in `pkg` dir. Then just run

```
$ sudo gem install pkg/built-gem-0.0.1.gem
```

**Edit**: appending BaroqueBobcat's wisdom verbatim from comment for better visibility:

This will only work if there is a Rake task for building the gem. If there is no rake task, but there is a `.gemspec` file, you can use `$ gem build <name>.gemspec`.

Comment: This will only work if there is a Rake task for building the gem. If there is no rake task, but there is a `.gemspec` file, you can use `$ gem build <name>.gemspec`.

Comment: BaroqueBobcat, your answer is what I was looking for, thanks a ton!

Comment: How do you push changes in the gem after the initial rake build and installation?